# How to convert VB script array to JavaScript array classic asp

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

Classic asp:

```
sub a

aryaa(0,0)=1
aryaa(0,1)=2

end
```

how to call this array in script function, and how to make this vbscript array to javascript array.

Please help me out from this, since 3 days i m searching for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any code you can post.  you will get a more meaningful answer then

Comment: Please post what you have tried. Or at the very least post your vbScript array code.

Comment: ...and have you already read up on javascript arrays? One place to start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: this may be helpful to you http://wiki.mcneel.com/developer/scriptsamples/arrays

Comment: yesterday i tried with this but not able to use it properly..

Comment: Are you using both Javascript and VbScript in Server side code? Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose MY VBScript array is aryATTPlans than the below code describe ( VBScript array to Javascript array)

```
// this is client JS code
var aryATTPlans = new Array();  
var aryATTPlans = new Array(2); 
var i, j;
<%
' this is server VBS code
If IsArray(aryATTPlans) Then
    j=0
    For i = 0 to ubound(aryATTPlans)
        %>
        aryATTPlans[<%= i %>] = new Array(2);
        aryATTPlans[<%= i %>][<%= j %>] = <%= aryATTPlans(i, j) %>;
        <% 
    Next // i
End If 
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript you don't have a native Matrix object type. But you can use either Object or Array such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var aryaa = [ [1, 2] ];
    // aryaa[0][0] = 1
    // aryaa[0][1] = 2
</script>
```

I hope you find this useful. Check [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The following function will convert a multi-dimensional VB safe-array into a multi-dimensional JavaScript array.

```
function VBtoJSArray(vba) {

    var vbarray = new VBArray(vba);

    var d = vbarray.dimensions();

    var dims = [];
    var base = [];
    var params = [];

    for (var i=1; i <= d; i++) {
        dims.push(vbarray.ubound(i)-vbarray.lbound(i) + 1);
        base.push(vbarray.lbound(i));
        params.push(vbarray.lbound(i));
    }

    return convertArray(new Array(dims[0]), 0);

    function convertArray(ax, index) {

        for (var i=0; i < dims[index]; i++) {

            params[index] = i + base[index];

            if (index == dims.length-1) {

                ax[i] = VBArray.prototype.getItem.apply(vbarray, params);
            }
            else {

                ax[i] = new Array(dims[index+1]);
                convertArray(ax[i], index+1);
            }
        }
        return ax;
    }
}
```