# How to store a asp recordset in javascript multi-dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp-classic

I'm trying to store a recordset in a multi-dimensional array in javascript, this is my current code:

```
<%
var cn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var strConn ="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource=(...).mdb;"

cn.Open(strConn);

var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Questions;"

rs.Open(sql,cn);

var count = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Questions;"

count.Open(sql,cn);

var total = count(0);

questions = new Array(total);

for (i = 0; i < total - 1; i++) {
   questions[i] = new Array(10);    
}

for (i = 0; i < total - 1; i++) {
   for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      questions[i][j] = rs(j);
   }
}
%>
```

I already tried to use `.GetRows()`.
I'm using IIS which is configured to run the javascript.
I've been in this for hours, I'm driving crazy!!!
Can someone help me, Please?

Comment: You really should use ajax and do this on back-end...

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I'm using IIS in Windows 8 do I need to install anything else to use ajax?

Comment: Does this JavaScript code run as part of an `.asp` file in IIS? Or is it run as HTML inside the browser? I'd assume the former, but you might want to be more explicit about that.

Comment: It runs in the IIS, sorry I was thinking on putting a note in the question about that but assumed that wasn't necessary.

Comment: That looks very much like client side Javascript. Can you confirm that it is enclosed either in <% %> or within `<script language="javascript" runat="server"></script>` tags

Comment: it's enclosed `<% %>`, I will include them in the question

Comment: I know it works in the server-side because made a test to display the query results, and it works, also I tried to run e several browsers besides IE since ActiveXObjects only works in IE, and in both chrome and firefox work

Comment: OK, I use VBS for most of my classic asp, I'm not completely familiar with JS equivalents, but I think you should be using Server.CreateObject rather than new ActiveXObject - see this link http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/051999-3.shtml

Comment: @John I have a equivalent file with VBScript, and I can pass the recordset to an array using `.GetRows()` but unable to store that VBScript array to Javascript, if you know a way, I would prefer to use VBScript.

Comment: @John it gives me this error: `800a01c2` if I use `Server.CreateObject`

Comment: Old question about converting arrays - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441321/how-to-convert-vb-script-array-to-javascript-array-classic-asp

Comment: Tried that before, I tried again now but gives me this error `800a0400` trying to fix it

Comment: Still the same problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always mix VBS and JS in the same page, eg

```
<%@LANGUAGE="Javascript" CODEPAGE="65001"%>

<script language="VBScript" runat="server">    
Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

cn.Open "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=" & Server.Mappath("../pathto/yourdb.mdb") 
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql = "SELECT * FROM Questions"

rs.Open sql,cn,3,1

Set count =  Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Questions"

count.Open sql,cn,3,1

total = count(0)
</script>

<%
questions = new Array(total);

for (i = 0; i < total - 1; i++) {
   questions[i] = new Array(10);    
}

for (i = 0; i < total - 1; i++) {
   for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      questions[i][j] = rs(j);
   }
}
%>
```

Comment: You have been helping me for a few posts already if you didn't notice and I really, really apreciate your help.
Thanks a lot.